# What exactly is occuring in this StackExchange error page?

Tags: discussion

[image: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/fail-panda.jpg]

https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/authenticate

Meta enough for you?

EDIT: Thank you, BoltClock. I was able to construct an image with my approximation of the panda's anatomy:

[image: Panda rough anatomical diagram]

Not my finest work, but I *was* having some trouble identifying the panda as a panda.

Comment: It appears to be a panda sitting on its head. Is... is there something about this that confuses you?

Comment: Where...where is its head?...oh, wait a minute, I think I might be able to figure this out...hmm.

Comment: -1 freehand circles missing

Comment: @KevinPanko I don't think the method of circle-making affects the quality of the question.

Comment: *just kidding did not downvote*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The panda tried to slide down the slide, but tumbled over and landed on its head. Clearly there is an error in either the slide's construction or the panda's programming, and one of them needs to be fixed.

Comment: Or maybe there's a hidden bamboo stash under there...